# How do I update a column value in my custom plugin with a simple controller?

Tags: plugin-development, controller, queries

I have a custom element type with its own table 'pluginname_entries'. I am trying to find a way to "dummy proof" changing the plugins status. So I came up, aka stole from the Events element type, with the idea of clicking a button that triggers a controller action - similar to the following example to delete my element types entry:

**actionDelete()**

```
/**
 * Deletes an entry.
 */
public function actionDelete()
{
    $this->requirePostRequest();

    $entryId = craft()->request->getRequiredPost('entryId');

    if (craft()->elements->deleteElementById($entryId))
    {
        craft()->userSession->setNotice(Craft::t('Entry deleted.'));
        $this->redirectToPostedUrl();
    }
    else
    {
        craft()->userSession->setError(Craft::t('Couldn’t delete entry.'));
    }
}
```

I love the concept or a quick way to delete or update the entry, more specifically the entry custom status, with a simple click of a button. So I came up with this:

**actionDeny()**

```
/**
 * Changes an entry to denied.
 */
public function actionDeny()
{
    $this->requirePostRequest();

    $status = PluginStatus::Denied;

    $entryId = craft()->request->getRequiredPost('entryId');

    $query = craft()->db->createCommand()
        ->select('id, status')
        ->from('entries')
        ->where(array(
            'id' => $entryId
        ))->queryRow();

    if ($query == null) {
        craft()->userSession->setError(Craft::t('Unable to deny the entry.'));
    }
    else {
        craft()->userSession->setNotice(Craft::t('The entry was denied.'));
    }

}
```

That works as intended, notifying the user but of course doesn't actually update the `status` column to the new value, is there a better way to handle this? Maybe more of a "Craft" way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are currently performing a `SELECT`instead of an `UPDATE` so no data will be updated.

I'm guessing that `entryId` is the primary key of the record you are trying to update? If so, I would suggest you find the record to make sure it exists, update its attributes (status) and then save it.

```php
// PluginController
public function actionDeny()
{
    $this->requirePostRequest();

    $status  = PluginStatus::Denied;
    $entryId = craft()->request->getRequiredPost('entryId');

    if (craft()->pluginName->updateStatus($entryId, $status)
    {
        craft()->userSession->setError(Craft::t('Unable to deny the entry.'));
    }
    else
    {
        craft()->userSession->setNotice(Craft::t('The entry was denied.'));
    }
}

// PluginService
public function updateStatus($id, $status)
{
    $record = PluginRecord::model()->findById($id);

    if ($record)
    {
        $record->setAttribute('status', $status);

        return $record->save();
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception(Craft:t('No record was found with id {id}', array('id' => $id));
    }
}
```

Unless I'm missing something, that should be about all you need.

[@selvinortiz](http://twitter.com/selvinortiz)